# Haproxy request gets timeout when doing ACL

Tags: haproxy

I created one simple application and i'm running it in 4 different containers.

I managed to proxy all the ports to the bind 9991, but when i create acl to use different backends it does'nt work, only the default back-end.

***Any tips for using haproxy will be very usefull!***

**haproxy.cfg :**

```
frontend tests
  bind *:9991

  timeout client 60s
  mode http

  acl is_servers_2 path_end /app2
  use_backend servers_2 if is_servers_2

  acl is_servers_3 path_end /app3
  use_backend servers_3 if is_servers_3

  default_backend servers_2

backend servers_2
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout server 60s
  mode http
  server server3001 127.0.0.1:3001
  server server3002 127.0.0.1:3002

backend servers_3
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout server 60s
  mode http
  server server3003 127.0.0.1:3003
  server server3004 127.0.0.1:3004
```

**haproxy version: 2.4.4**

**ubuntu: 18.04**

Comment: Can you paste the config under `defaults` section?

Comment: This config is everything i have inside my haproxy.cfg @RahulSharma

Comment: May be the url that you're trying to access haproxy with doesn't have `/app2` or `/app3` at their end?

Comment: That's very possible. If that's the case, you can use something like `http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/app\d,/,g)]` in the backend to strip the `\app#` from the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed my api was the problem.

It wasn't configured to handle /app2 and /app3 path urls, just /